# Comparing sale price $220 regular $260

Tags: grammar

Im making a massage flyer and in the middle my deal is a massage bundle of 4 sessions. Then it shows the price $220 and under it im not sure if it should say regular $260, or usual $260, standard $260?? What is the correct way to word this?

Layout looks like this:

4 Sessions
  $220 
Regular $260

So they see the sale amount but what is the correct way to say it.. keep in mind the shorter the better as im limited on space.

Thanks!

Comment: By "regular" do you mean four individual sessions would normally cost $260?

Comment: Yes, so the massage bundle saves them $40 in total and $10 per individual massage so it comes out to be $55/1hr massage. The regular price is $65 and 4 massages would total $260

Comment: Can you add "special discount"? What's the word limit?

Comment: No thats too long. What im really trying to do is just to compare the 2 price points to make the saving visible. I might go with "regularly $260" thats about the max i can fit.

Answer (score 2):

"4 sessions, $220 (regular price, $260)"

"4 sessions, $220 (regularly $260)"

"4 sessions, $220 (priced individually, $260)"

Comment: Ok, so Regularly $260 fits in the space. I think Ill use that unless there is something better. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Karl you can also use "usually" or "normally" instead of "regularly" - I think that sounds better.

Comment: Yeah regularly sounds weird to me but if its correct then Ill use it. Maybe "Normally" would fit better. 4 sessions $220 normally $260. I dont know anymore haha I guess either one will work.

Comment: "Regularly" is unclear, I realized after I posted it, because it doesn't specifically mean that $260 is the cost of the sessions separately. It could also mean that *the package* of 4 sessions is usually $260, without being understood to be saying anything at all about the price if the sessions were priced individually. It's clearer to write "priced individually, $260" or "$260 if purchased separately". Now I see @HighTechGeek's answer with "SAVE", which is a good one.

Comment: "It could also mean that the package of 4 sessions is usually $260" Thats what I am trying to get across though. So Im saying 4 sessions $220 ( which is the discounted rate) Normally $260 for 4 sessions without the discount. I cant use save $40 as that is my headline already. I think "normally" works good. What do you think?

Comment: I meant that it could imply that a *package* of 4 sessions is usually $260, with the possibility that, purchased separately, they would cost even more.

Comment: ah I see which is why you said "regularly" is unclear. Gotcha.

Answer (score 2):

4 Sessions: $220 (reg $260)

4 SESSIONS: $220 (SAVE $40!)